# How to acces data in a relation using parse.com

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com, and I have in Data Browser the following tables: User (the default user table) and studyYears. In my User table, I have multiple users. I have added to the user table a column of Relation type that refers to another table called studyYears. The studyYears table only contains a string column called year.

How can I make a query that for a user I will get the values from the year column of the studyYears table?

I hope somebody can understand what I am trying to get. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Coredata, SQLite? In order to help you we need some more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am using parse.com and by using the iOS sdk, I am trying to make a query to get the values from a relation table.

Answer (score 5):

http://blog.parse.com/2012/05/17/new-many-to-many/ states:

> When you fetch the Place object, the objects in the relations won’t be
>   fetched, which is a huge win for a relationship with a large number of
>   objects. Even without fetching all the objects in the relation, you
>   can add objects to the relation using add:. If you wanted to fetch all
>   the objects in the relations, you would do something like:

```
PFRelation *relation = [place relationForKey:@"likes"];
PFQuery *query = [relation query];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    // results contains all the people who liked Sid's BBQ.
}];
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I am getting a Error: a valid pointer is needed for RelatedTo operator (Code: 102, Version: 1.2.7).

Comment: I have posted a more detailed issue with a screeenshot here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457291/parse-com-relational-query-issue