# Parse.com relational query issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have the following tables name "aniStudii" and "discipline", I have made a screenshot as well:

[image]

As you can see, there is a relation between these tables, at the "materii" column. The row from "aniStudii" with the column "Anul I" has a value and the other column has a different value, values that can be found in the "discipline" table.

I am using this query to get the values, but all I get is Error: bad pointer for key: _p_materii (Code: 106, Version: 1.2.8)

This is my query:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"aniStudii"]; //1
PFObject *aniStudiu = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"discipline"];
[query whereKey:@"materii" equalTo:aniStudiu];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",results);
}];
```

Where is the problem? A big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this, where you start from a specified object (which you may need a query to find):

```
PFObject *sourceObject = ...;

PFRelation *relation = [sourceObject relationforKey:@"materii"];

[[relation query] findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",results);
}];
```

To get the first object you can perform a query something like:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"aniStudii"];
[query whereKey:@"numeAn" equalTo:@"######"];
```

Comment: `PFObject *sourceObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"aniStudii"];

    PFRelation *relation = [sourceObject relationforKey:@"materii"];
    
    [[relation query] findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",results);
    }];`

And I get 

`2013-05-09 11:53:40.438 licentaUser[2873:1b03] Error: a valid pointer is needed for RelatedTo operator (Code: 102, Version: 1.2.8)
2013-05-09 11:53:40.440 licentaUser[2873:c07] (null)`

Comment: You need an instance of PFObject which has been retrieved from the server. You can't just create a new instance (which is what objectWithClassName does) and then query the relation.

Comment: PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"aniStudii"];
    PFObject *sourceObject = [query getObjectWithId:@"xWMyZ4YEGZ"];
    PFRelation *relation = [sourceObject relationforKey:@"materii"];
    
    [[relation query] findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",results);
    }];

This works, but I have to know the objectId to make the result happen. I don't want that, is there anyway to go around this?

Comment: You can query for the source object by name or creation date (or any other field it has). Or, you can query for all instances of a particular object (paginated) and display them for the user to choose...

Comment: query hasn't got any other options besides getObjectWithId. So instead of ` PFObject *sourceObject = [query getObjectWithId:@"xWMyZ4YEGZ"];` I don't know what else to use.